# Tool for Automation Testing on unity-webplayer

Tags: testing, ui-automation, unity-web-player

I need a automation tool for my web application that develop in unity webplayer. I am a beginner in Unity development, a complete step-by-step tutorial would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Integration Test Framework in the Unity Test Tools
Integration Tests allow you to automate the verification process of your assets directly in a scene. They are designed to be used on existing content, directly within the Editor, to build tests which verify the behaviour of single assets or the interaction between them.

How to use the Integration Test Framework you can read here https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unitytesttools/wiki/IntegrationTestsRunner